# Want to plot spectral exitance versus wavelength

Tags: plotting

I am an undergraduate student trying to plot spectral exitance versus wavelength for a gray body. I am a beginner with *Mathematica* and I cannot figure out why I have no plot.  This code was my attempt at doing it with just a black body. Please help.

```
M[λ_] := 
  (2*π*(6.626*10^-34)*(2.9979*10^8)^2)/λ^5 * 
    1/(Exp[((6.626*10^-34)*(2.9979*10^8))/(λ*1.38*10^-23*505.928)] - 1)

Plot[M, {λ, 0, 0.02}]
```

Comment: You need := to define a function

Comment: Your parentheses are unbalanced, you used `C` vice `c` in the function, the definition of `M` is missing an `=`, you are not consistent with use of symbol `\[lambda`] and you did not include the argument to `M` in the `Plot` command.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 1):

Your parentheses are unbalanced, you used `C` vice `c` in the function, the definition of `M` is missing an `=`, you are not consistent with use of symbol `λ` and you did not include the argument to `M` in the `Plot` command.

```
h = 6.626*10^-34;
c = 2.9979*10^8;
k = 1.38*10^-34;
T = 505.928;
M[λ_] := (2*π*h*c^2)/(λ^5)*1/
   Exp[(h*c)/(λ*k*T - 1)]

Plot[M[λ], {λ, 0, 0.000002}]
```

[image]

You might want also to look at [LogPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogPlot.html)

```
LogPlot[M[λ], {λ, 0, 0.000002}]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, ok.  I think it is working now.  Thank you!